Memory Error in Multi threading mode of Bullet3: A simple Example
I am experimenting with the multithreading capability of bullet. In the following simple example I get unknown address error. The btCollisionConfiguration is initialized correctly and I would appreciate some insight into the problem. here is the code:
#include <btBulletDynamicsCommon.h>
#include "BulletDynamics/ConstraintSolver/btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolverMt.h"
#include "BulletCollision/CollisionDispatch/btCollisionDispatcherMt.h"
#include "BulletCollision/BroadphaseCollision/btDbvtBroadphase.h"
#include "BulletCollision/CollisionShapes/btBoxShape.h"
#include "BulletDynamics/Dynamics/btDiscreteDynamicsWorldMt.h"

int main() {
    btDbvtBroadphase* broadphase = new btDbvtBroadphase();
    btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolverMt* solver = new btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolverMt();
    btDefaultCollisionConstructionInfo cci;

    cci.m_defaultMaxPersistentManifoldPoolSize = 10;
    cci.m_defaultMaxCollisionAlgorithmPoolSize = 10;
    btCollisionConfiguration* collisionConfig = new btDefaultCollisionConfiguration(cci);
    btCollisionDispatcher* dispatcher = new btCollisionDispatcherMt(collisionConfig);
    btDiscreteDynamicsWorld* dynamicsWorld = new btDiscreteDynamicsWorld(dispatcher, broadphase, solver, collisionConfig);
    dynamicsWorld->setGravity(btVector3(0, -10, 0));

    btBoxShape* boxShape = new btBoxShape(btVector3(1, 1, 1));
    btScalar mass = 1.0;
    btVector3 localInertia(0, 0, 0);
    boxShape->calculateLocalInertia(mass, localInertia);
    btTransform startTransform;
    startTransform.setIdentity();
    startTransform.setOrigin(btVector3(0, 50, 0));
    btDefaultMotionState* motionState = new btDefaultMotionState(startTransform);
    btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo rbInfo(mass, motionState, boxShape, localInertia);
    btRigidBody* body = new btRigidBody(rbInfo);
    dynamicsWorld->addRigidBody(body);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        dynamicsWorld->stepSimulation(1.f / 60.f, 10);
    }

    // Cleanup
    delete body;
    delete motionState;
    delete boxShape;
    delete dynamicsWorld;
    delete solver;
    delete broadphase;
    delete dispatcher;
    delete collisionConfig;

    return 0;
}

here is my Cmake file:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(PhysicsSimulation)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED TRUE)
ADD_DEFINITIONS( -DBT_THREADSAFE=1 )

if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug")
endif()

if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
    add_compile_options(-fsanitize=address)
    add_link_options(-fsanitize=address)
endif()

find_package(Bullet REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "Bullet libraries: ${BULLET_LIBRARIES}")
message(STATUS "Bullet include directories: ${BULLET_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

add_executable(PhysicsSimulation PerformanceTest.cpp)

target_include_directories(PhysicsSimulation PUBLIC ${BULLET_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(PhysicsSimulation PUBLIC ${BULLET_LIBRARIES})

set_target_properties(PhysicsSimulation PROPERTIES
    DEBUG_POSTFIX "_Debug"
    MINSIZEREL_POSTFIX "_MinsizeRel"
    RELWITHDEBINFO_POSTFIX "_RelWithDebugInfo"
)

Here is the error:
=================================================================
==10700==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000000 (pc 0x00010473fff4 bp 0x00016b6db190 sp 0x00016b6db120 T0)
==10700==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
==10700==Hint: address points to the zero page.
    #0 0x10473fff4 in btCollisionDispatcherMt::btCollisionDispatcherMt(btCollisionConfiguration*, int)+0x64 (PhysicsSimulation_Debug:arm64+0x10001bff4)
    #1 0x104727ccc in main PerformanceTest.cpp:54
    #2 0x18bf320dc  (<unknown module>)

==10700==Register values:
 x[0] = 0x0000000000000000   x[1] = 0x0000000000000023   x[2] = 0x0000000000000023   x[3] = 0x0000000108400010  
 x[4] = 0x0000000108400280   x[5] = 0x0000000000000000   x[6] = 0x000000016aee0000   x[7] = 0x0000000000000001  
 x[8] = 0x0000000104770000   x[9] = 0x00000001081039d0  x[10] = 0x0000000000000005  x[11] = 0x00000000ffffffff  
x[12] = 0x0000000000000000  x[13] = 0xda122256f3c39294  x[14] = 0x0000000000007e01  x[15] = 0x0000000000000006  
x[16] = 0x0000000105044a98  x[17] = 0x00000001050840b8  x[18] = 0x0000000000000000  x[19] = 0x0000000108400200  
x[20] = 0x0000000000000028  x[21] = 0x000000016b6db360  x[22] = 0x0000000104b9d910  x[23] = 0x000000016b6db3e0  
x[24] = 0x0000000108405354  x[25] = 0x000000018bfa62db  x[26] = 0x0000000000000000  x[27] = 0x0000000000000000  
x[28] = 0x0000000000000000     fp = 0x000000016b6db190     lr = 0x000000010473fff4     sp = 0x000000016b6db120  
AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV (PhysicsSimulation_Debug:arm64+0x10001bff4) in btCollisionDispatcherMt::btCollisionDispatcherMt(btCollisionConfiguration*, int)+0x64
==10700==ABORTING
zsh: abort      


Please also consider that the computer has an M3 chip on it. I tried checking the address memory and it fails in btCollisionDispatcherMt initilization. I am not sure whether it is because of bad bullet3 setup that I have in my code or it is related to missing pieces in building the sdk. Just note that I built the SDK in double precision mode.
UPDATE:
I did some debugging using lldb and the output of frame variable is nullptr after stepping into new btCollisionDispatcherMt(collisionConfig):
(lldb) run
Process 12734 launched: '/Users/.../Documents/InternalCode/PlayGround/Bullet/C++/Arena/MT1/build/PhysicsSimulation_Debug' (arm64)
Process 12734 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x0000000100003458 PhysicsSimulation_Debug`main at PerformanceTest.cpp:53:41
   50       cci.m_defaultMaxPersistentManifoldPoolSize = 10;
   51       cci.m_defaultMaxCollisionAlgorithmPoolSize = 10;
   52       btCollisionConfiguration* collisionConfig = new btDefaultCollisionConfiguration(cci);
-> 53       btCollisionDispatcher* dispatcher = new btCollisionDispatcherMt(collisionConfig);
   54       // btDiscreteDynamicsWorld* dynamicsWorld = new btDiscreteDynamicsWorld(dispatcher, broadphase, solver, collisionConfig);
   55       // dynamicsWorld->setGravity(btVector3(0, -10, 0));
   56   
Target 0: (PhysicsSimulation_Debug) stopped.
(lldb) frame variable
(btDbvtBroadphase *) broadphase = 0x0000000103503ac0
(btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolverMt *) solver = 0x0000000100203790
(btDefaultCollisionConstructionInfo) cci = {
  m_persistentManifoldPool = nullptr
  m_collisionAlgorithmPool = nullptr
  m_defaultMaxPersistentManifoldPoolSize = 10
  m_defaultMaxCollisionAlgorithmPoolSize = 10
  m_customCollisionAlgorithmMaxElementSize = 0
  m_useEpaPenetrationAlgorithm = 1
}
(btCollisionConfiguration *) collisionConfig = 0x0000000103d03880
(btCollisionDispatcher *) dispatcher = 0x00000000000002c0
(lldb) step
Process 12734 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x00000001006613b4 libBulletCollision.3.26.dylib`btCollisionDispatcherMt::btCollisionDispatcherMt(btCollisionConfiguration*, int) + 108
libBulletCollision.3.26.dylib`btCollisionDispatcherMt::btCollisionDispatcherMt:
->  0x1006613b4 <+108>: ldr    x8, [x0]
    0x1006613b8 <+112>: ldr    x8, [x8, #0x18]
    0x1006613bc <+116>: blr    x8
    0x1006613c0 <+120>: mov    x21, x0
Target 0: (PhysicsSimulation_Debug) stopped.
(lldb) frame variable
(lldb) 


I'll suggest to post the github link of the library you use.

@LouisGo please find the link to the repo the following. I built the master branch; https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3

Have you tried the hello world program in their doc? I found dynamicsWorld - > setGravity(...); might be required.

@LouisGo I am doing that by dynamicsWorld->setGravity(btVector3(0, -10, 0)); and yes I was able to compile the hello world in addition to a self written code but the multi thread version of the collision dispatcher causes the problem
